# P8Z68-V PRO BIOS output gone after switching to HDMI inputs on monitors

Tags: windows-7, video, bios, hdmi, dvi

I have a newly built machine with an ASUS P8Z68-V PRO MB, ASUS GeFore 210 Silent video card and Windows 7 Prof. Everything configured fine upon install with the output from the 210 going to two Dell 2408 monitors on the DVI inputs. (The 210 has a DVI and an HDMI, so the latter had an adapter.)

Because the 2408 monitor has known problem with its DVI inputs (intermittent loss of video) I switched to the HDMI inputs on the monitors. (The adapter is now on the DVI output of the 210).

Everything still works, except that I get no BIOS display. Both monitors have no signal until the Win7 login screen appears. I've tried each monitor as the only monitor connected and still see nothing until the Win7 login screen. I also tried the VGA output of the 210 to a third monitor, along with the two Dells but it never displayed anything. The on-board outputs never put out anything either.

Any ideas why this is happening?